Term store admin cannot create or delete term sets
I have a term store admin access where i can able to see the term sets but somehow I cannot create,delete or update the term sets. And i see this message "You don't have permission to save changes". But I do not have SharePoint Global admin access.
How to make sure I can create or delete term sets without Global Admin access or any alternative access ?

Could you access the term store admin page? Whether you have admin role for the term store?

Yes i have admin role for the term store and can access the page.

Whether you create or delete all term sets?

I cannot create or delete any term sets.
